# локатор содержащий текст с переменным символом

Tags: javascript, xpath, css-selectors

нужен локатор который будет искать элемент по тексту при этом допуская что в массиве текста один символ может иметь одно из двух возможных значений.
например я ищу кнопку которая содержит число

```
//a[contains(.,"123,123")]
```

но в веб-приложении на одной странице числа разделяются запятой, а другой точкой. а если открывать его с иноязычной операционки (ну типа в русском десятичная часть отделяется запятой, а в английском точкой), то вообще белиберда с этими точками и запятыми..

моя задача сделать локатор который находит элемент учитывая что в нём может быть как точка так и запятая.

моё временное решение это проверять оба локатора ожидая что один из них пройдёт.

подойдёт решение в виде локатора css/xpath либо javascript

xpath v1.решение должно воспроизводиться в этих вкладках [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: объедини оба локатора (к которым обращаешься дважды) в один через `OR`

Comment: это плохое решение, является временным

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Решение с использование JavaScript**

Находим нужный элемент и проверяем с помощью регулярного выражения

```
document.querySelector("a").innerHTML.match(/123(.|,)123/);
```

Более подробную информацию о том как написать регулярное выражение, можно найти в справочниках по функции `match()`.

Answer (score 0):

Если кто-то ищет решение чисто на XPath, то можно воспользоваться оператором `or`:

```
//a[contains(., "123.123") or contains(., "123,123")]
```

Comment: это плохое решение, мне не подходит. и его очень легко найти как на этом ресурсе, как загуглить, так и просто догадаться